# How to remove object from array JSON with filter DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, any

I have this output

```
    {
  "array": [
    {
      "value": "abc",
      "Product2": {
        "Name": "phone",
        "id": "123abc"
      },
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "123abc",
          "value": "PKabc"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From this I need to remove entire object from "**products**" array if **value** and **id** (in the **array** ) is the same in the "**products**" array

I'm trying in this way but not work

```
(payload.array filter ($.value == $.value))
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The JSON provided is the input for this question, not the output. What happens when there are multiple elements in each array? Show some examples of the expected output for this questions for different inputs.

Comment: and `$.value == $.value` is always true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the `payload.array` array and then filter by the value attribute over the products array.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.array map ((arrayItem, arrayIndex) ->
    arrayItem.products filter ($.id != arrayItem.value) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

### %dw 2.0
output application/json

payload.array map if(($.products map $.id) contains $.Product2.id)($ - "products") else $